# Отсутствует указатель текущей версии Node

Tags: node.js

Ввожу команду nvm list, мне выдает список установленных версий, но отсутствует указатель текущей версии "*". В месте с этим системе не удается найти указанный путь при вводе команды node -v.
Что делать?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nvm list

    19.3.0
    18.12.1
    17.9.0
    16.15.1
    16.0.0
    14.20.1
    14.15.4
```

Я до этого вводил какую-то команду, для решения проблемы с тем же node и у меня после этого пропало отображение указателя. Эту команду уже не помню и найти не могу.

Comment: `nvm set default=19`?

Comment: @Qwertiy скорее `nvm set default system`

Comment: @nörbörnën Да! Вроде она. Есть способ как исправить?

Comment: @user20389696 я понимаю о чем ваш вопрос, но у меня нет windows, так что не могу поэксперименировать и дать нормальный совет

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось одновременно просто и сложно, для тех кто не знает как исправлять.
Заходим в файл package.json, находим установленные расширения.

```
"dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
```

В моем случае это выглядит так. Сохраняем их в отдельный файл, что бы потом не искать, что у нас установленно. Далее в ручную устанавливаем один за другим, начиная с react, потом react-dom , потом react-scripts и так далее по важности. То есть вписываем в dependencies по одному расширению и через npm i устанавливаем. И САМОЕ ВАЖНОЕ - нужна более новая версия каждого пакета.

Comment: как этот ответ связан с вопросом о версии node?

Comment: @Grundy В это трудно поверить, но напрямую. Мне помогли. Проблема в путях. Он не могу найти путь к node не потому, что у меня проблема была в ноде, а в том, что все версии пакетов были старыми. Я наверно не смогу ответить более развернуто, опыта не хватает. Но этот способ помог и все заработало.

Comment: `package.json` в котором ты делал изменения, никак не связан с тем, что выводит команда `nvm`.